# Change font and size of button - no designer or jquery!

Tags: template, script

I have created links to document templates using the source code as opposed to URL (URL links do not open read only and not in the relevant library) - I used the guide [here](https://jennyssharepointtips.wordpress.com/2014/07/30/launch-document-content-type-templates-from-any-web-page-with-a-link/)

And have created a button for it.

The button works fine!  BUT, I want to make it and the font bigger, I have tried a few different variations of `font-size= XXpt` but nothing seems to work.

This is the script, using script editor (the company links have been taken out.

```
<input type=button onClick="CoreInvoke(&#39;createNewDocumentWithRedirect2&#39;,event,&#39;LINK.pptx&#39;, &#39;ADDRESS&#39;, &#39;SharePoint.OpenDocuments&#39;, false, &#39;https://ADDRESS/_layouts/15/CreateNewDocument.aspx?id=https://LINK;, true, 1)" value='Want to add a Safety Moment? Drag&Drop it onto the library under if you have one ready, or click here for the template. 'style="background: url( https://image.png )">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another attribute for your button i.e. `style` attribute. You can put any style you like within it. In your case you can go with following code:

```
<input type="button" style="font-size: 24px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;" onClick="CoreInvoke(&#39;createNewDocumentWithRedirect2&#39;,event,&#39;LINK.pptx&#39;, &#39;ADDRESS&#39;, &#39;SharePoint.OpenDocuments&#39;, false, &#39;https://ADDRESS/_layouts/15/CreateNewDocument.aspx?id=https://LINK;, true, 1)" value='Want to add a Safety Moment? Drag&Drop it onto the library under if you have one ready, or click here for the template. 'style="background: url( https://image.png )">
```

Comment: I have no idea how that didn't work before but copying and pasting now works a treat!  Thank you :)